# How to display content in a circular drop-down menu with small width and height

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a select element and i want to display 1m, 2m, 3m if it's not opened yet, when it's opened it will display another content

[[image: initial state[![when menu opened]when menu is opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAlqE.png)

the main problem i face is that the 2 characters doesn't fit in the circular menu to be displayed with trying text-indent property.

```
handleDateField = e => {
        let date = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            date
        })
}   

handleCircullarSelect = (e) => {
        if(e.target.options.length > 0) {
            this.setState({
                open: !this.state.open
            })
        }

}

<select 
 onChange={this.handleDateField}
 onClick={this.handleCircullarSelect}                              
 class={`form-control circle ${!this.state.open ? "short-date" : ""}`}
>
    <option disabled value="0">Choose a date</option>
    <option value="1">{this.state.open ? "Last Month" : "1m"}</option>
    <option value="2">{this.state.open ? "Last 2 Months" : "2m"}</option>
    <option value="3">{this.state.open ? "Last 3 Months" : "3m"}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just transform selected value into 1m, 2m, 3m. We can't help you, because there are not enough information and no code examples.

Comment: @demkovych i'll add more information now

Comment: could you share `handleDateField` function?

Comment: @demkovych done

Answer (score 0):

Just add a formatted value to select:

```
<select 
  value={`${this.state.date}m`}
  onChange={this.handleDateField}
  class={`form-control circle ${!this.state.open ? "short-date" : ""}`} 
/>
```

You can also add a defaultValue to select, which uses, when nothing was selected:

```
<select defaultValue={`${this.state.date}m`}
```

Comment: it didn't work cause the problem isn't about what is the value, it's about how can i display this value (1m) in the rounded select knowing that its width is :calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px)